# Rails best practise for accessing API wrappers in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating my first Rails application and I'll be integrating a few other apps, like Mandrill, Xero and such.

I'm just wondering what best practises are on storing instance variables globally. For example, I don't want to configure my Mandrill wrapper instance in each of my controllers. I want to do it in one spot and make a call to it whenever I need to send an email out.

Is `application_helper.rb` the spot to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a service for that. As the matter of fact you can check http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ which is a great way to do your applications flexible, testable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I haven't looked in to Rails services yet, this might be a good excuse to do so

Comment: Here is a sweet article on creating Services, for anyone else that may come this way in the future
https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Comment: Yes, it is important to say that these services are, in fact, POROs ( Plain Old Ruby Objects). Name service is kind of reserved for communication with other applications/APIs and interactor is used for services for internal use. For the second one you can use 'interactor' gem.